# Significato di "acquari" nel racconto "Piombo" di Primo Levi

Tags: word-meaning

Nel racconto *Piombo* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Ma poco sotto il piombo c’era: e questa è una cosa a cui spesso avevo pensato, che noi cercatori crediamo di trovare il metallo con gli occhi, l’esperienza e l’ingegno, ma in realtà quello che ci conduce è qualcosa di piú profondo, una forza come quella che guida i salmoni a risalire i nostri fiumi, o le rondini a ritornare al nido. Forse avviene per noi come per gli **acquari**, che non sanno che cosa li guida all’acqua, ma qualcosa pure li guida, e torce la bacchetta fra le loro dita.

Dovete sapere che il narratore in questo racconto è un cercatore di piombo.

Non sono sicura di cosa siano questi "acquari" che appaiono nel testo.

Ho cercato "acquario" in parecchi dizionari, inclusi il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/acquario1) e il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* ([[1](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000140.jpg)] e [[2](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000141.jpg)]), ma non ho trovato nessuna accezione che possa avere senso nel contesto del testo.

Si tratta magari di qualcuno capace di trovare l'acqua sotteranea con l'aiuto di una bacchetta? Se è così, usare "acquario" con questo significato è un'invenzione di Primo Levi?

Comment: Dal contesto si direbbe proprio che stia parlando dei rabdomanti; chiamarli “acquari” effettivamente non mi risulta, ma per esempio [qui](https://www.beic.it/sites/default/files/attachments/La%20lingua%20delle%20acque.pdf) si apprende che tra l'altro li si è chiamati “fontanieri”, e quindi forse esistono varie denominazioni locali.

Comment: (Tra parentesi: in teoria potrebbe essere anche il plurale di “acquaro”, ma non risulta da nessuna parte se non come nome di un comune in Calabria.)

Comment: “Acquario“, come  sinonimo di “fontaniere” viene citato su etimo.it - https://www.etimo.it/?term=acquario

Comment: @Hachi: Grazie per la segnalazione, ma vedi [qui](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1202/37) sul fatto che etimo.it va preso con enorme cautela.

Comment: @DaG - si che non è una fonte autorevole, ma mi sembrava valesse la pena citarla.

Comment: Avvallo l'ipotesi del rabdomante, visto che parla di "bacchetta" che "li guida all'acqua" e che si "torce tra le dita"